# Superclass for ostream and fstream

Tags: c++, c++11, iostream

I'm trying to make my own logging class in C++ using a wrapper class in which i overloaded operator<< that sends it to the cout. Now I want to change it, so that when i create instance of that class, i can pass and argument that logs data in std::cout or some file i create. What is the exact type that is superclass of both fstream and ostream? I tried with std::ios&, std::basic_ios&, std::basic_ostream& and none of them seems to work (throwing me compilation error).

```
class myostream {
public:

    static int getlogLevel() {
         return loglevel;
    }
    static void setlogLevel(int i) {
         loglevel = i;
    }
    myostream(std::basic_ios& cout, int level)
    : _cout(cout), _level(level)
    {}

    template<class T>
    std::ostream& operator<<(T t) {
        if(_level >= loglevel) {
             _cout << loglevelcolor[_level] << loglevelname[_level]  << " "  << t << COL_RESET << std::endl;

        }

        return _cout;
    }
private:
    static int loglevel;    
    std::basic_ostream& _cout;
    int _level;
};
```

Comment: `std::basic_ostream` is a template, `std::ostream` is probably what you want here.

Comment: When posting questions regarding build errors, always include the errors you get. Copy them, as text and in full and complete, and paste them without modifications into the question body. Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also, trying to find [a good input/output reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io) would probably help you as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the exact type that is superclass of both `fstream` and `ostream`?

It is `std::ostream`, which is an alias to `std::basic_ostream<char>`. See the class diagram for [`std::fstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream).

Example:

```
class myostream {
public:
    myostream(int level) // Log into stdout.
        : _cout(std::cout), _level(level)
    {}

    myostream(char const* filename, int level) // Log into a file.
        : _file(filename), _cout(_file), _level(level)
    {
        if(!_file.is_open())
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to open " + std::string(filename));
    }

    // ...

private:
    std::ofstream _file;
    std::ostream& _cout;
    int _level;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Use base class [`std::ostream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/ostream) which is typedef for [`basic_ostream<char>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream), reference: [iostream hierarchy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io).

Works for me (std::cout, std::ofstream):

```
#include <iostream>

class myostream {
public:
    myostream(std::ostream& out)
    : _out(out)    {}

    template<class T>
    std::ostream& operator<<(T t) {
        _out << "test"  << " "  << t << '\n' << 42 << std::endl;
        return _out;
    }
private:  
    std::ostream& _out;
};
```